# Reversing a LinkedList Recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have been trying to reverse a linkedlist recursively in java. I've worked out a solution on paper but when I try to implement it in code, it keeps failing. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am missing here?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Solution {

    public static class LinkedListNode {

        public int value;
        public LinkedListNode next;

        public LinkedListNode(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static LinkedListNode reverse(LinkedListNode headOfList) {
        
        LinkedListNode newHead = headOfList;
        LinkedListNode nextNode = headOfList.next;

        if (headOfList == null) { 
            return null;
        }
        
        if (headOfList.next == null) {
            return headOfList;
        }
        
        else {
            reverseNodes(newHead, headOfList, nextNode);
            headOfList.next = null;
        }

        return newHead;
    }
    
    public static void reverseNodes(LinkedListNode head, LinkedListNode a1, LinkedListNode a2) {
        
        if(a2.next == null) {
            a2.next = a1;
            head = a2;
        }
        else {
            LinkedListNode nextNode = a2.next;
            reverseNodes(head, a2, nextNode);
            a2.next = a1;
        }
        
                
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `headOfList.next` before even checking if `headOfList` is null

```
if (headOfList == null) {
      return null;
    }
```

this should stand right at the top of your `reverse` function
Here you trying to set the head to a value but this only effects the method parameter you cannot overwrite a value of a pointer.

```
public static void reverseNodes(LinkedListNode head, LinkedListNode a1, LinkedListNode a2) {

    if(a2.next == null) {
      a2.next = a1;
      //Strange assignment has no sence
      head = a2;

    }
    else {
      LinkedListNode nextNode = a2.next;
      reverseNodes(head, a2, nextNode);
      a2.next = a1;
    }

  }
```

Example for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "12345";
    System.out.println("outside of method x = "+x);
    changeVariable(x);
    System.out.println("outside of method x = "+x);
  }
  
  public static void changeVariable(String variable){
    variable = "hello";
    System.out.println("inside of method x = "+variable);
  }
```

Will result:

```
outside of method x = 12345
inside of method x = hello
outside of method x = 12345
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Here you trying to set the head to a value but this only effects the method parameter you cannot overwrite a value of a pointer." I assumed that since these are references, the head reference will only change one we get to the tail and we don't need to return anything.

Comment: I mean with that it has no effect to set the head variable because this only changes the reference in your function

Comment: I've added a example

Comment: @srachoor to notify you